What is the highest land Speed per level?
What is the highest permanent Speed you can get without a set class?

Elves start with 30.
1st level: Nimble Elf gives them +5 (35)
3rd level: Fleet +5 (40)
5th level: Trick Magic Item and Wand of Tailwind +10 (50)
7th level: Boots of Bounding +5 (55)
14th level: Boots of Bounding (Greater) +5 (60)

What did I miss?

Would multiclass archetypes be included in a set class?

No, archetype away

The List
I've tried to include every option for each level that matters where maximum speeds might change, and generally included limited-time options as separate values. I also opted to include multiple bonuses even if they're lesser in case the costs of using them is lower, for comparing consumables vs permanent items and other options.
In terms of spellcasting, I included wands at the level of the item rather than basing it around Trick Magic Item. While that is a way for any character to cast these spells, many characters might find an easier way to cast these particular spells or just automatically qualify to cast them.

1st level: 35 feet, 40 with panache, 45 with 1-minute consumable:

Nimble Elf as mentioned increases base speed to 35
Ancient Elf heritage with the swashbuckler archetype for panache, granting a +5-foot status bonus to speeds (normally only during combats)
1st-level consumable lesser prey mutagen grants a +10-foot status bonus for 1 minute


2nd level: 35 feet, 40 with panache, 45 while traveling in favored terrain or with 1-minute consumable or starting turn in 1-minute consumable or with 1-hour consumable, 55 downhill with 1-hour consumable:

Horizon Walker grants a +10-foot circumstance bonus to travel speed in a specific type of terrain

Not enough feats to have this with panache, and the bonus is overshadowed by other archetypes later on


2nd-level consumable white spun cloud grants a +10-foot item bonus to creatures starting their turn in the cloud which lasts 1 minute
2nd-level consumable oil of skating grants a +20-foot status bonus to downhill speed for 1 hour, or a +10-foot status bonus otherwise (with some penalties)


3rd level: 40 feet, 45 with panache, 50 while traveling in favored terrain or with 1-hour spell or with 1-minute item activated or starting turn in 1-minute consumable or with 1-hour consumable, 60 with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 70 with 1-minute spell:

3rd-level item wand of tailwind as mentioned, granting a +10-foot status bonus
3rd-level item wand of fleet step, granting a +30-foot status bonus for 1 minute
Fleet as mentioned, granting a +5-foot bonus
3rd-level consumable moderate prey mutagen grants a +20-foot status bonus for 10 minutes
3rd-level bracelet of dashing grants +10-foot status bonus for 1 minute, once per day


4th level: 50 feet, 60 with 1-hour spell or with 1-minute item activated or starting turn in 1-minute consumable or with 1-hour consumable, 70 with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 80 with 1-minute spell:

Werewolves and Wereboars in their animal shape have a base speed of 30 feet when taken as part of the rare 2nd-level Werecreature Dedication
Notably this is not described as a battle form in the Howl of the Wild, allowing that speed to be used without the same limitations described in the polymorph trait preventing things like Fleet or Nimble Elf from applying.
Animal Fleetness as a 4th-level archetype feat grants a +10-foot bonus to that animal form speed
Not enough feats to have this and panache at level 4 due to dedication requirements


5th level: 50 feet, 55 on snow or ice or with 10-minute consumable, 60 while traveling or with 1-hour spell or with 1-minute item activated or starting turn in 1-minute consumable or with 1-hour consumable, 70 with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 80  with 1-minute spell:

5th-level item ring of the weary traveler grants a +10-foot item bonus to travel speed
5th-level item snowshoes of the long trek grants a +5-foot status bonus on ice and snow
5th-level consumable egg cream fizz granting a +5-foot item bonus for 10 minutes


6th level scout alternative: 60 feet, 70 while traveling or with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 80 with 1-minute spell:

Scout's Speed for +10-foot status bonus to speed always and a +20-foot status bonus to travel speed
The wand of tailwind and Swashbuckler archetype can be dropped
Not enough feats to have this and werewolf/wereboar speed at level 6, resulting in a drop while taking a mutagen
6th-level item vaultbreaker's harness grants a +10-foot item bonus for 1 minute, unlimited use as a single action so I've included it in the base speed


7th level: 65 feet, 70 during first round of combat or on ice or snow, 75 while traveling or with 1-hour consumable, 85 with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 95 with 1-minute item activated or with 1-minute spell:

Fleetwind Centaur heritage granting a +5-foot bonus

Combined with Adopted Ancestry for elves to keep Nimble Elf and  picking up Fleet at 7th level
Cheers to Ifusaso for this spot
The heritage mentions hooves specifically, so wereboar might be required rather than werewolf


7th-level item fire robe grants +30-foot status bonus for 1 minute, once per day
7th-level meal sweet pancakes increase your speed by 5 feet during the first round of combat for the day after you last ate them, assuming they're your favorite meal and were prepared correctly of course
Maximum speeds require the wereboar build, though travel speed without items is still highest with the scout


8th level: 75 feet, 80 during first round of combat, 85 with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable or while traveling, 95 with 1-minute item activated or with 1-minute spell:

Finally enough feats to have Wereboar and Scout's Speed
Only possible at 8th level due to the Scout Skill feat Eclipsed Vitality requiring master proficiency in Stealth


9th level 75 feet, 80 during first round of combat, 85 with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable or while traveling, 95 with 1-minute item activated or 1-minute spell cast on us:

9th-level item wand of elemental gift grants a +30 status bonus for 1 minute
Notably this spell can be cast by an ally, rather than something we need to take


10th level: 80 feet, 85 during first round of combat, 90 with 10-minute consumable or downhill with 1-hour consumable or while traveling, 100 with 1-minute item activated or 1-minute spell cast on us:

Member of a Bellflower Tiller's crop while they have Tiller's Drive, granting a +5-foot circumstance bonus
Not something we can take—only benefit from


11th level: 80 feet, 85 during first round of combat, 90 downhill with 1-hour consumable or while traveling, 100 with 1-hour consumable or with 1-minute item activated or 1-minute spell cast on us:

11th-level consumable greater prey mutagen grants a +30-foot status bonus for 1 hour


15th level: 80 feet, 85 during first round of combat, 90 downhill with 1-hour consumable, 95 while traveling, 100 with 1-hour consumable or with 1-minute item activated or 1-minute spell cast on us:

Legendary Guide requiring legendary proficiency in Survival, granting a +10-foot circumstance bonus to travel speed
Technically we don't need this feat if someone else in the group has it


16th level: 80 feet, 85 during first round of combat, 90 with 1-minute focus spell or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 95 while traveling, 100 with 1-hour consumable or with 1-minute item activated or 1-minute spell cast on us:

Shifting form Wizard focus spell, granting a +20-foot status bonus
Requires Wizard Dedication, Basic Arcana, and Advanced Arcana at 16th to take the 8th-level Advanced School Spell feat
Included as more easily usable than the once per day fire robe or consumables


17th level: 90 feet, 95 during first round of combat, 100 with 1-minute spell or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 105 while traveling, 110 with 1-minute item activated or 1-minute spell cast on us, 120 with 1-hour consumable:

Animal Swiftness with the beastkin heritage for a beast lacking alternative speeds, granting a +10-foot bonus

Centaur heritage is incompatible and grants a lesser bonus


17th-level consumable major prey mutagen grants a +40-foot status bonus for 1 hour
17th-level item jerkin of liberation, granting a +15 item bonus to speed


19th level: 95 feet, 100 during first round of combat, 105 with 1-minute spell up or downhill with 1-hour consumable, 110 while traveling, 115 with 1-minute item activated or 1-minute spell cast on us, 125 with 1-hour consumable:

20th-level artifact the cricket, granting a +20 item bonus to speed at 19th character level



The Build
The 20th-level build includes the following:

Werecreature animal form (30)
Animal Swiftness beastkin heritage feat (+10)
Nimble Elf ancestry feat (+5)
Fleet general feat (+5)
Animal Fleetness werecreature feat (+10)
Scout's Speed scout feat (+10 status, +20 status to travel)
Member of a Bellflower Tiller's crop (+5 circumstance)
In a party with a Legendary Guide (+10 circumstance to travel)
Bearer of the cricket (+20 item)

Giving a base speed of 95, increased by:

Sweet Pancakes favorite meal, eaten every day (+5 first round every combat)
Major prey mutagen (+40 status for 1 hour)

Up to a maximum of 130 feet Speed in the first round of combat reliably. Various alternatives exist if we're not willing to drop 3,000 gp an hour and/or take the prey mutagen penalties against animals and beasts.
Honorable Mentions
Earning a major boon of Gozreh at any level would gain a permanent +30-foot status bonus to speeds. This still isn't the largest status bonus thanks to the major prey mutagen's +40, but it would make the Scout archetype and various other pieces irrelevant.
Additionally, the psi cantrip tesseract tunnel has some very neat applications with a very high speed. There are plenty of other abilities that benefit from speed but the amped version of this "with a range equal to your Speed" could enable some real shenanigans.

You have most of it
In fact, you have everything I'm aware of prior to the newest book, Howl of the Wild. Howl of the Wild adds Centaurs, who also begin with 30ft base movement, with a Heritage to increase it to 35. Noting just the changes:

Fleetwind Centaurs start with 35
3rd level: reveal that you were Adopted (Ancestry) by Elves
5th level: Nimble Elf +5 (40)
7th level: Fleet +5 (45)
14th level: total with your other bonuses = 65

